# How to get the correct repetition value and package name in maven-surefire-plugin XML report for @RepeatedTest annotation test cases in junit

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin, test-reporting

I have created some JUnit test cases as per below hierarchy.

Package name e.g :

`test.qa.paramter.myTest`

Under this package, i have 2 test cases:

1: First Test case(with class name NormalTest and method name as caseNormalTest) with @Test annotation

2: And second test case (with class name RepeatTest and methods name as caseRepeatTest) with @RepeatedTest which will repeat the same test 2 times with different input values.

my question is how i can get the same classname xml output for @RepeatedTest as its not displaying the full package name. Also is it possible to get the repetition count in the surefire report?

Now when i run the test case using Jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin generate the test result xml for @RepeatedTest

```
<testcase name="caseRepeatTest" classname="caseRepeatTest()" time="30.636"/>
<testcase name="caseParametrization" classname="caseParametrization()" time="13.013"/>
```

whereas for @Test annoation i m getting

```
<testcase name="caseNormalTest" classname="test.qa.paramter.myTest.NormalTest" time="22.796"/>
```

below is my POM setting

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx2048m</argLine>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
         <sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders>true</sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders>
            <testInstance>v1</testInstance>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
        <includes>
            <include></include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Maven Surefire 2.22.0 or higher and remove the dependency on the obsolete `junit-platform-surefire-provider`.

Details here: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven